# Ask about product reCaptcha

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart, captcha

I have a problem with captcha on my website. When I want to ask question about product, captcha is not showing and after asking it writes message "Code is not valid". I've been searching for solution for last 2 days and I found nothing that helped me.

**My website:**
[URL](http://www.skladoleju.cz/motorove-oleje/total-quartz-ineo-mc3-5w-30-3x-5-l-detail.html)

website is in czech language, so you are looking for button "zeptejte se na produkt" (orange button right under 2-3 Days image)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I see a div which seems exists as a placholder for reCaptcha, but I also see a js error in your page pertaining the reCaptcha - Error: ReCAPTCHA placeholder element must be an element or id. So try to fix this at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. In file /plugins/captcha/recaptcha/recaptcha.php replace these lines (62 - 68):

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$theme   = $this->params->get('theme', 'clean');
$document->addScriptDeclaration('jQuery(document).ready(function($){$(window).load(function() {'
. 'grecaptcha.render("' . $id . '", {sitekey: "' . $pubkey . '", theme: "' . $theme . '"});'
. '});});'
);
```

with this single line:

```
JHtml::_('script', 'plg_captcha_recaptcha/recaptcha.min.js', false, true);
```

Note: I modified this file after updating joomla (because
of similar problem - it solved the problem), but after updating virtuemart a few months later, my "patch" (not mine, I had found it somewhere on forum) stopped working. So I undone changes (by replacing these lines) and it started to work again.